# Updating EXIF data to save media with latest date on IOS react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, exif, camera-roll

While I am downloading a photo from URL to Camera Roll, photo get saved with created date on IOS device, I need photo to be saved with current date.
I need to modify the original exif metadata of the photo file.
Is there any way to save the photo to Camera Roll By updating all it's exif metadata?